# input not aligned with image SCSS

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a problem. I want to make an input that will be equal to the picture, be on a par with it, but I get this:

[image]

Partially I understand why this is, the picture lies in a div, on which the input is aligned, but I do not know how to change its height.
My markup looks like this:

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  h1 {
    font-family: "Roboto Light";
  }
}

.image {
  display: inline;
  img {
    height: 56px;
    display: inline;
    margin: 10px 0;
    width: 141px;
    pointer-events: none;
    /*элемент не может стать объектом мыши*/
    user-select: none;
    /*запрет на перенос текста*/
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
  }
}

.input {
  padding: 10px 100px;
  display: inline;
  input {
    height: 60px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sass.js/0.6.2/sass.min.js"></script>
<div className={main.wrapper}>
  <div className={main.container}>

    <div className={main.image}>
      <img src={require( "./components/UI/img/img.png")}/>
    </div>

    <div className={main.input}>
      <input/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Help me, please

Comment: try to add to your container: display:flex; flex-direction: column;

Answer (score 0):

Just add `display: flex;`  to `.container`.
As alternative you can also use `inline-flex` (depends on your usage).

```css
.container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;

    h1{
        font-family: "Roboto Light";
    }

}
```

As alternative (depends on your usage) you can also user `inline-flex`.